# How to destroy an many-to-many object and its link in DataMapper/Sinatra/Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-datamapper

I am a newbie and would appreciate some help on how to resolve this problem.  I have tried to follow the documentation in DataMapper and have not found any solutions via Google on how to destroy an object and its corresponding links.  Here are the key code segments.

**The Model**

```
class Entity
```

include DataMapper::Resource

property :entity_id,        Serial
  property :full_legal_name,  String
  property :tax_id,           String
  property :phone_number,     String
  property :fax_number,       String
  property :cell_number,      String
  property :email,            String, :unique => true, :format => :email_address
  property :alt_email,        String
  property :is_active,        Boolean
  property :created_at,       DateTime
  property :created_by,       String
  property :updated_at,       DateTime
  property :updated_by,       String
  property :auto_pay,         Boolean
  property :use_ach,          Boolean
  property :prefix,                        String
  property :first_name,                    String
  property :middle_name,                   String
  property :last_name,                     String
  property :suffix,                        String
  property :referral_code,                  String
  property :login_name,                    String, :unique => true
  property :hashed_password,               String, :length => 200
  property :salt,                          String
  property :permission_level,              Integer
  property :title,                         String
  property :greeting,                      String
  property :preferred_name,                String
  property :preferred_language,            String
  property :security_question,             String
  property :security_answer,               String
  property :signature_font,                String
  property :auth1_checkbox, Boolean
  property :auth2_checkbox, Boolean
  property :auth3_checkbox, Boolean
  property :auth4_checkbox, Boolean
  property :auth5_checkbox, Boolean
  property :auth6_checkbox, Boolean
  property :digital_signature, String
  property :date_signed, DateTime
  property :signatory_ip, String
  property :signatory_title, String

has n, :addresses, :through => Resource
  has n, :aches
  has n, :creditcards

end

class Person < Entity

property :birthdate,                     String
  property :drivers_license_number,        String
  property :state_issuing_drivers_license, String

end

class Company < Entity

property :dba_name,        String
  property :legal_structure, String
  property :url,             String, :format => :url

end

class Address

include DataMapper::Resource

property :address_id,        Serial
  property :esid,              String, :unique => true
  property :description,       String
  property :address_line1,     String
  property :address_line2,     String
  property :city,              String
  property :state,             String
  property :zipcode,           String
  property :country,           String
  property :meter_number,      String
  property :meter_type,        String
  property :meter_status,      String
  property :meter_status_date, DateTime
  property :updated_by,        String
  property :switch_indicator,  String
  property :switch_type,       String
  property :selected_switch_date, Date
  property :under_contract,    Boolean
  property :contract_end_date, Date

has n, :entities, :through => Resource

end

**Object creation and Persistence**

```
     if session[:base_route].to_s == "residential"
   #residential processing
   @entity_id = session[:this_person].inspect
   @person = Person.get(@entity_id.to_i)
   @address = Address.new()
   @address.esid = params[:post][:esid]
   @address.description = params[:post][:service_location_description]
   @address.address_line1 = params[:post][:service_address_line1]
   @address.address_line2 = params[:post][:service_address_line2]
   @address.city = params[:post][:service_city_name]
   @address.state = params[:post][:service_state_name]
   @address.zipcode = params[:post][:service_zip_code]
   @address.switch_indicator = params[:post][:switch_indicator]
   @address.switch_type = params[:post][:switch_type]
   params[:post][:under_contract_checkbox]  == "on" ? @under_contract = true : @under_contract = false 
   @address.under_contract = @under_contract

   @person.addresses << @address

   if @person.save
```

**Attempted object and link destruction (The link is destroyed, but the address destruction does not work)**

```
    @entity_id = session[:this_person].inspect
    address = Address.get(params[:post][:submit].to_i)
    address.destroy
    entity = Entity.get(@entity_id)
    link = entity.address_entities.get(@entity_id, params[:post][:submit])
    link.destroy
```

Any tips or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just a newbie suggestion u can pass params[:post] in to your Address.new methods as Address.new(params[:post) it will reduce lot of codes. This happens because the params are passed as a hash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deletion of the answer object failed because there was a link between the answer object and the entity object.  By reversing the order and deleting the link first and the object second, the object is destroyed.

```
@entity_id = session[:this_person].inspect
entity = Entity.get(@entity_id)
link = entity.address_entities.get(@entity_id, params[:post][:submit])
link.destroy
address = Address.get(params[:post][:submit].to_i)
address.destroy
```